# mongodb cryptic error process.nextTick(function() { throw err; }) ^ Error at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When attempting to start my MEAN app after adding mongoose and a couple of mongoose Schemas, I'm getting a strange error.

```
node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Projects/node/flapper-news/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:42:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Projects/node/flapper-news/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/index.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**routes**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Post = mongoose.model('Post'),
    Comment= mongoose.model('Comment');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    Post.find(function(err, posts){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(posts);
    });
});

router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(post);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**schemas**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

I previously had schemas and mongoose connect call *after* declaring `app = express()` in **app.js**, but that threw a different error. Can someone spot where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Include your stack trace (the block of text that appears directly below the error message.) Within the stack trace, it will likely point to a line within one of your files.

Comment: It's not letting me add it the question because my question is mostly code, and it's too lengthy for a comment. Here's a gist:
https://gist.github.com/mchandleraz/129b14b5389ae25b17a9

It's just pointing to some mongo core stuff.

Comment: What version of mongoose?

Comment: Basically, in this case, I would go to the files/lines mentioned in the stack trace and investigate where the error originated from.

Comment: @KevinB mongoose is v4.0.2

Comment: Ok, the error is being caught from here: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/server.js#L226 this suggests that mongoose tried to connect and failed, then tried to execute an error callback and failed, so it then finally just threw an error.

Comment: Have you tried adding connect and error callbacks to your mongoose connection?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've added a callback, which confirms your suspicion about the connection to mongo failing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2-line NodeJS application crashes on mongoose.connect() while trying to connect to a mongolab MongoDB database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926210/2-line-nodejs-application-crashes-on-mongoose-connect-while-trying-to-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't created the /data/db directory for my MongoDB install. Created the directory and set myself as the owner, and everything works now.

Comment: where did u added that directory? i get the same error

Comment: I'm on OS X Yosemite, and created the directory at the disk root. A leading slash indicates disk root, ie: `/data/db` would be at the root, while `data/db` would be a subfolder of the current directory.