# 2-line NodeJS application crashes on mongoose.connect() while trying to connect to a mongolab MongoDB database

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I have the following NodeJS code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://dev:dev@ds031632.mongolab.com:31632/mongodev');
```

And upon running it with `node server.js`, it hangs up for a few seconds and throws the following:

```
C:\Users\dev\work\code\local\nodejsplayground\restwithmongo\nod
dules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dev\work\code\local\nodejsp
round\restwithmongo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mong
core\lib\error.js:42:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dev\work\code\local\nodejsp
round\restwithmongo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mong
core\index.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I pinged the server by console via this:

```
ping ds031632.mongolab.com
```

I tried installing mongodb with the windows installer and it's still not working

Comment: Add an error handler, you'll get far more useful error output.

Comment: with a try catch? or can you explain?

Comment: no, a mongoose connect error handler. read docs.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html checking this and no sign of an error handler. Only allows for an extra options parameter

Comment: nevermind, found it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback

Comment: hmm.. your right, it's not in the docs anymore... weird... It does show the fact that .connect accepts a callback though. I use `connection.on('error'`

Comment: Added the callback, got nothing. Check my edit

Comment: how long did you wait? it sometimes takes a little while for it to timeout. be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when there is an error connecting to mongodb without an error callback to be called. To fix this error (and get the actual error,) add a callback to the .connect method, or, bind to the error event.

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongodb, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

or

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongodb);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('mongodb connection error: %s', err);
  process.exit();
});
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Successfully connected to mongodb');
  app.emit('dbopen');
});
```

---

If you find that nothing happens and it just hangs, wait 30 or so seconds and it will timeout, which simply means mongoose couldn't connect to mongodb, which could be caused by a very large number of different things, mostly related to network/dns/firewall/server configuration.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. Running it on a VM in another network and it runs fine.

Comment: It's likely your network just wasn't allowing that outgoing port. My network does the same, i had to request for it to be opened. I instead ended up going with an ssh tunnel.